# Intellij complaining about property logging.file.path in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Running Springboot 2.5.9 and IntelliJ 2022.1.  I have this in my application.yml:

[image]

However, IntelliJ is complaining about the fact that `logging.file` is deprecated.  `logging.file.name` and `logging.file.path` are correct usages as far as I know.  Is this just an IntelliJ bug?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue, updating IntelliJ IDEA from 2022.1 to 2022.1.1 solved the problem for me:

[image]